# Getting R 3.0 in Ubuntu

Tags: r, ubuntu, apt-get

I am currently using **R 2.15.3** (Security Blanket) in Ubuntu. **R 3.0** is already released, but I could not update to it using apt-get. Will there be any trouble if I install it from tar.gz from cran website?

Comment: You may need the development version of external packages to which it links, but as far as stability goes, Linux is the main development platform for R, so you should be fine. There is a mailing list for Debian/Ubuntu questions: https://stat.ethz.ch/mailman/listinfo/r-sig-debian

Comment: Thank you.
Any idea when will .deb for R 3.0 be available ?

Comment: I'm a Mac user so I don't even know what that means. Looking back at last month's archive for sig-debian I see a link to this page that may be helpful: http://www.personal.psu.edu/mar36/blogs/the_ubuntu_r_blog/2013/03/moving-to-r-300-on-ubuntu.html

Answer (score 5):

R 3.0.0 has been available for Ubuntu essentially since the release, the procedure is always the same: I update the package for Debian (unstable), Michael takes these and rebuilds them on launchpad for several Ubuntu releases.  See the [very clear README at the CRAN mirrors](http://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/README.html).

This time, however, it is a little different as R 3.0.0 requires you to updated all R packages as well.  So so far, Michael provides the binaries only via his rdev PPA, not the one mirrored to CRAN.  This was explained in detail [in a post to r-sig-debian](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.r.debian/2024) and [on his blog](http://www.personal.psu.edu/mar36/blogs/the_ubuntu_r_blog/2013/03/moving-to-r-300-on-ubuntu.html) (which is syndicated to R Bloggers etc).

Comment: The following command line gets you started: `add-apt-repository ppa:marutter/rdev`.